# How does WindowsPhone10 tell its platform in cordova-plugin-device

Tags: javascript, cordova, uwp, cordova-plugins, windows-10-mobile

I know I can recognize Windows Phone 7 as "WinCE" and Windows Phone 8 as "Win32NT" in cordova-plugin-device with command:

```
platform === 'WinCE' || platform === 'Win32NT'
```

but how about Windows Phone 10?

We don't have success on offline storage and I would like to know if there is a miss on this line.

I would like to ask, what is the alternative on that if for WP10?

Comment: Question is does the WP10 platform fall through these ifs or does it need its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the WP10 platform fall through these ifs or does it need its own?

I just tested it on windows phone 10 and the output of `device.platform` is `windows`:
[image]